# Using PreparedStatement to sort records in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, sorting, jdbc

Im trying to write a code in which when a user will click an a "Sort by Name" button, my program will sort the records of my Database and put them in a JTable,combining 2 DB Tables with INNER JOIN. I have managed to do this by using a resultSet and selecting for example Ascending Order. But because I dont want to have 2 buttons, one for the ASC and one for the DESC, I thought of using preparedStatement and an showInputDialog in which the user will select if he wants to have an ASC or a DESC ordering and execute the order. Also, I remembered that some programs I've seen used a feature in which the first time you clicked the button it sorted DESC and if you pressed it again would order by ASC(havent managed to find in on the WEB).About my first thought, I tried to do it but I could get past this one

```
ResultSetMetaData mdsort = rssort.getMetaData();
```

I should have an ResultSet variable(rssort) to use getMetaData() but if I selected to make the program with my PreparedStatement i would get an error there. Any suggestions??

```
try{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    Statement stmtsort = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rssort = stmtsort.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id ORDER BY consoles.name ASC");
       // ERROR HERE!!! needs resultset,not preparedStatement
    ResultSetMetaData mdsort = rssort.getMetaData();
    columnCount = mdsort.getColumnCount();
    String[] colssort = new String[columnCount];
    for (i=1;i<= columnCount;i++)
       {
        colssort[i-1] = mdsort.getColumnName(i);
       }
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colssort,0);
    while (rssort.next())
       {
            Object[] rowsort = new Object[columnCount];
             for (i = 1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++)
             {
               rowsort[i-1] = rssort.getObject(i);
             }
        model.addRow(rowsort);
       }
      JTable table = new JTable(model);
      model.fireTableDataChanged();
      table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
      table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
      table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
      table.setBounds(218,59,529,360);
      frame.getContentPane().add(table); 
      model.fireTableDataChanged();
      conn.close();
      stmtsort.close();
      rssort.close();
      } catch (SQLException case1)
                {case1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception case2)
                {case2.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE**

OK I managed to fix this issue with the getMetaData() but now the thing is that I dont use any ResultSet variables/instances and cant use next() method to create my DB.

```
String name = "SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id ORDER BY consoles.name ?";
PreparedStatement psname = conn.prepareStatement(name);
String strin =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ASC or DESC order ? : ");
psname.setString(1,strin);
psname.executeUpdate();
ResultSetMetaData mdsort = psname.getMetaData();
int columnCount = mdsort.getColumnCount();
                     .
                     .
                     .
// error coming up here,because i deleted the ResultSet

 while (psname.next())
           .
           .
           .
```

Comment: Please include the actual stacktrace if you get an error. Also you are not using a `PreparedStatement` in your code

Comment: you have an issue with curly braces

Comment: A different approach may be to read the data sorted ASC ( as you currently do ) and just sort the resulting model in your code, rather than returning to the database, if the user asks to see it in reversed order. But I agree with Ajit - we need to see the error you are getting.

Comment: Updated it on my post so you could see my code

Comment: `psname.executeUpdate();` .... you are not updating... You need to use whichever preparedstatement method returns a result set instead.

Comment: So you saying that i should somehow "cast" the PreparedStatement to a ResultSet?

Answer (score 2):

Better make a bit more complex TableModel.

That is more optimal.

Keep the data from the ResultSet in an original TableModel.
Use a wrapping TableModel to sort, and maybe filter.

Use the ResultSetMetaData for the column type, if it is Number (Integer, BigDecimal, ...) then use that type instead of Object for the column type: gives a right aligned column.

Maybe first do an internet search for ResultSetTableModel; other peoply must have done it already.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
       String strin =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ASC or DESC order ? : ");
       stmtsortname = conn.createStatement();
       rssortname = stmtsortname.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id ORDER BY consoles.name "+strin);
       mdsortname = rssortname.getMetaData();
       columnCount = mdsortname.getColumnCount();
       String[] colssortname = new String[columnCount];
       for (i=1;i<= columnCount;i++)
            {
                colssortname[i-1] = mdsortname.getColumnName(i);
            }
       model = new DefaultTableModel(colssortname,0);
        while (rssortname.next())
           {
            Object[] rowsortname = new Object[columnCount];
             for (i = 1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++)
             {
               rowsortname[i-1] = rssortname.getObject(i);
             }
            model.addRow(rowsortname);
          }
    table = new JTable(model);
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true)  
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
    table.setBounds(146,59,763,360);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table); 
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    conn.close();
    stmtsortname.close();
    rssortname.close();
   } catch (SQLException case1)
      {
        case1.printStackTrace();
      }
     catch (Exception case2)
      {
        case2.printStackTrace();
      }
}
});
```